# Конфликт между \documentclass{book} и lstlisting

Tags: latex

Готовлю довольно большой документ, который (предполагается) будет содержать *\chapter*. Кроме того, документ содержит множество листингов - *\lstlisting*.

Возник конфликт: если я объявляю класс документа *book*, то выдаются ошибки на листинги:

```
Paragraph ended before \lstenv@testopt@ was complete.
```

А если объявляю класс документа *article*, то ругается на разделы:

```
Undefined control sequence. \chapter
```

Есть решение этой проблемы?

Comment: да вроде бы book и listings [вполне совместимы](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286008/79376). может быть, у вас какая-то ошибка в использовании listings, которая проявляется только при смене article на book? попробуйте составить [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку минимального примера пока нет, я проверил принципиальную возможность дружить класса `book` с командами из пакета `listings`. Пишу как ответ, а не комментарием, т.к. привожу пример с кодом - в комментарии это будет совсем не красиво.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Новая глава}
Готовлю довольно большой документ, который (предполагается) будет содержать 
\lstinline[language={tex}]!\chapter!. 
Кроме того, документ содержит множество листингов.

\begin{lstlisting}[language={gnuplot},caption={Пример листинга},backgroundcolor=\color{blue!10!white}]
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"
plot sin(x) with lines linewidth 2
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

У меня в Miktex 2.9 образца примерно 2015 года - все собралось без ошибок как через `pdflatex`, так и через `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf`.

Я специально проверил как работу окружения, так и работу отдельной внутристрочной команды (`lstinline`). Поэтому для решения проблемы автора вопроса *очень желателен* минимальный пример, который вызывает ошибку при сборке.

[image: Результат сборки]

Comment: После мучительного стучания фэйсом об тэйбл обнаружил, что в директиве *\begin{lstlisting}[frame=tlBR, caption={Заголовок}]* потерял закрывающую ']'... Не сразу разобрался с этим, т.к. сообщения об ошибке различались в классах book и article, что и сбивало с толку :-( Прошу прощения за невнимательность!